# Can I query twice to get more specific value in mongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

For an example, there is a group called "A" which is an array.

And there is another group called "B" which is inside of group "A" also an array.

I want to find and update group "B" elements.

I tried to query chain-like query like in jQuery.

```
db.collection.findOne({"group":"A"}).findOne({"society":"B"})
```

something like this..

but this does not work. But main point is that I want to query group elements in group.

Any suggestion on doing this?

If you give me advice especially with PHP implementation, it will be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but what is wrong with:

```
db.collection.findOne({"group":"A", "society":"B"})
```

Also note that findOne only returns one document.

Comment: I mean. Querying on an already queried result. Is it possible?

Comment: I see. Not with the MongoDB driver alone, I think. Someone could implement that client-side.

Comment: This somewhat gave me inspiration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your document looks something like this:

```
db.mycol.insert( {
    "_id": 1,
    "group": "A",
    "societies": [
        {"society": "A", "name": "Alpha" },
        {"society": "B", "name": "Beta" }
    ]
} );
```

Then in the Mongo shell, you can retrieve the document you want using a query:

```
var group = db.mycol.findOne( { "group": "A" } );
```

And then further filter down on its fields using some client-side JavaScript:

```
var societyB = group.societies.filter(function (val) {
    return (val.society == "B");
} );

printjson(societyB);
```

You'd be able to do something similar with the PHP driver.  The key is to perform the action in separate steps: first grab the document you're interested in; then filter and manipulate its fields; then save it back to the database.